# How to create a executable jar file for Sabre red app plugin to install same plugin on others machine without using eclipse

Tags: sabre

I am new comer to develop Sabre red app using Eclipse IDE. I have created some sample plugin using Eclipse over SRW environment. I need help to create a executable jar file (or some installer file)for my sample Sabre red app plugin so that I can install this app on others machine and it shouldn't be require any Eclipse IDE.

My sample plugin app is running successfully in my machine using Eclipse. I just want to install this app on others machine as well. Please advise how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

In order to distribute your created Red App to end users of Sabre Red Workspace, you will have to submit to Sabre for Certification.

When it comes to distribution, you can do as either Public or Private Apps. Private Sabre Red Apps are apps that are unique to your agency’s needs and only available to your agency. They are not visible to users who are browsing the Red App Centre Marketplace.

More information can be found here:
https://www.sabreredappcentre.sabre.com/RAC/About/Overview.aspx